# all and any output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving one of the questions in hackerrank and this output confuses me:

```
>>> lil=[81]
>>> any([str(x)==str(x)[::-1] for x in lil])
False
>>> any([str(x)==str(x)[::-1]] for x in lil)
True
```

Can someone please explain how the second expression is being interpreted by Python 
 and why output is True?

Comment: It's giving me `True` for both programs.

Comment: all() just returns True/False, how are you obtaining a number out of that?

Comment: What is the problem statement in the first place?

Comment: if `lil` is not empty, `any([x] for x in lil)` (as you have in your second program) should be always `True`, no matter what's inside `lil`

Comment: My confusion is I am not able to understand the second output.

Answer (score 0):

Why the first one gives true for the **any** evaluation

```
[str(x)==str(x)[::-1] for x in lil]
[str(x)==str(x)[::-1] for x in [1, 81]]
[str(1)==str(1)[::-1], str(81)==str(81)[::-1]]
['1'=='1'[::-1], '81'=='81'[::-1]]
['1'=='1', '81'=='18']
[True, False]
```

I get error (rightly so) for the second version
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
This is because `[str(x)==str(x)[::-1]] for x in lil` is an invalid generator.

Note **any** is equivalent to

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Answer (score -1):

**any** is a function that works on a list. In second code you want to create a list using list comprehension. So in the second code, inside of the brackets of **any** list is not being generated as that command does not know where to look for x. The code

```
[str(x)==str(x)[::-1]]
```

is not generating any list, but the code

```
[str(x)==str(x)[::-1] for x in lil]
```

genrates.

Comment: `any` does not require a list. It takes any iterable. The version with the misplaced bracket is passing in a generator expression. (The generator yields nonsense, but the nonsense it yields should not produce the output the question claims.)